# how to disable shadow copy in resharper test runner?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper

I am using Jetbrains ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.1.

I unchecked Shadow-copy assemblies being tested. Here are my settings:

[image: Unit Testing Options]

I saved the settings and restarted Visual Studio Community Edition 2015.

I double checked - the settings are saved.

I execute a test using Resharper's test runner. I placed a debug point to check the path where the assemblies are running. They are in \appData. They are supposed to be executing from my solution folders. **How can I fix this problem?**

Here is an example of the assembly path, you can clearly see it is AppData and not my projects solution folder on my desktop:

[image: appData]

Comment: I found a fix to the issue. But I do not understand why. I simply switched from using nunit.framework.dll version 3.0.1 to 2.6.4. If someone could answer explaining why version 3.0.1 will not disable shadow copy I will award the points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReSharper Unit Test not run in bin directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222532/resharper-unit-test-not-run-in-bin-directory)